# Is it possible to remove specific repeated character of a list using regex?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a list of one column that contain ~ 100 lines,  in which some lines are repeated, and my purpose is to get rid of a **specific** duplicate lines and leave only **one** copy, while the other lines kept untouched.

An extract of the files that I'm working on :

```
V(Mn9)   
V(C1,H3) 
V(Mn6)   
V(Mn6)   
V(C4,H6) 
V(Mn9)   
V(Mn9)   
V(C1,Mn6)
V(C4,Mn9)
V(Mn6)   
V(C1,C4) 
C(Mn9)   
C(Mn6)   
C(C1)    
C(C4)    
C(Mn9)   
C(Mn6)   
V(C1,H2) 
V(Mn9)   
V(Mn6)   
V(C4,H5)
```

My purpose is to remove all the duplicate lines contain C(Xx0-9) and leave one of them and kept the V(Xxx..).

The result I seek :

```
V(Mn9)   
V(C1,H3) 
V(Mn6)   
V(Mn6)   
V(C4,H6) 
V(Mn9)   
V(Mn9)   
V(C1,Mn6)
V(C4,Mn9)
V(Mn6)   
V(C1,C4) 
C(C1)    
C(C4)    
C(Mn9)   
C(Mn6)   
V(C1,H2) 
V(Mn9)   
V(Mn6)   
V(C4,H5)
```

I used the command :

```
sed '0,/C(Mn9)/{/C(Mn9)/d}' inputfile.txt | sed '0,/C(Mn6)/{/C(Mn6)/d}'
```

and it's working, but it's not good enough for the whole file, because there is a lot of C(Xx1-50), I thinked to use regular expression, but I don't know how, that's why I need your help.

Comment: You want to remove the duplicates occurring first or last?

Comment: Can you mix the order of lines? Can you sort the file before removing duplicates?

Comment: It doesn't matter wich occurrence, the important thing is to keep one occurrence of each C(Mn1-50), without touching the others.

Comment: double check your desired output and specify if you wand the first unique C(XxN) of if you want the second. ie.. when should it be printed? the first time it is seen? or when it is detected as duplicate?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин doesn't matter wich one, the important thing is to keep one match. i.e. one C(Cl8) and one C(Cl7), and of course the other duplicate keep it untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(/^C\(..[0-9])$/ && seen[$0]++)' file
V(Mn9)
V(C1,H3)
V(Mn6)
V(Mn6)
V(C4,H6)
V(Mn9)
V(Mn9)
V(C1,Mn6)
V(C4,Mn9)
V(Mn6)
V(C1,C4)
C(Mn9)
C(Mn6)
C(C1)
C(C4)
V(C1,H2)
V(Mn9)
V(Mn6)
V(C4,H5)
```

The above assumes you have no white space before/after the visible characters in your sample input. If you do then remove them, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} !(/^C\(..[0-9])$/ && seen[$0]++)' file
V(Mn9)
V(C1,H3)
V(Mn6)
V(Mn6)
V(C4,H6)
V(Mn9)
V(Mn9)
V(C1,Mn6)
V(C4,Mn9)
V(Mn6)
V(C1,C4)
C(Mn9)
C(Mn6)
C(C1)
C(C4)
V(C1,H2)
V(Mn9)
V(Mn6)
V(C4,H5)
```

Comment: This solution does not take into account the order of the C(XxN) values, and produces output that is _different_ from the desired result as specified in the question. It does not matter though, because the order is not important for the author of the question.

Comment: The author already [stated in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675921/is-it-possible-to-remove-specific-repeated-character-of-a-list-using-regex/676169?noredirect=1#comment1276273_675921) that the output order doesn't matter. You can't expect them to provide every possible variation of output order in the question and it's pointless commenting on or editing every answer to say it has the desired behavior. if you feel it's not clear from the question that the order of output lines doesn't matter then edit the question (or ask the question author to clarify).

Comment: Strictly speaking your answer provides a solution without any explanation of how it works.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин who cares? It's a trivial little idiomatic awk script using absolutely basic awk constructs. Anyone who doesn't understand it will learn far more from google and the man pages than being spoonfed basic awk syntax and you can't expect every awk answer to explain basic awk syntax.

Comment: You win. I'm moving on.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин but not before downvoting my answer I see. OK, that's your prerogative.

Comment: I tried to modify the question so that the site would allow me change my vote, but you refused...

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин the solution given by Ed Morton is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `sed` to collect lines in the hold space to check whether they appeared before:

```
 sed -n 'H;G;/^\(C([^)]*)\).*\1 *\n/!P'
```

- `H` appends the current line to the hold space
- `G` appends the hold space with all lines we ever saw to the pattern space
- `C([^)]*)` is one of those `C(…)` patterns, the `^` anchors it to the beginning of the line and it's surrounded by `\(…\)`, so it can be backreferenced as `\1` later. We need `\1 *\n` as pattern, with the newline (after possible whitespaces) to avoid matching the freshly appended line at the end. So the whole pattern `/^\(C([^)]*)\).*\1 *\n/` matches a line with a duplicate `C(…)`, so only if this `!` doesn't match,
- `P`rint everything before the first newline (= without the appended hold space), while default output is suppressed by the `-n` option

Note that depending on you `sed` version and file size, this may fail because over the time, all lines will be in memory.

Comment: Sorry, but your command doesn't give any result.

Comment: I tested it on the file you provided … try by yourself by c&P ing your data to a file. Is it possible your actual file has some hidden characters like tabs or carriage returns (from DOS line endings)?